# STS Gradle project defaults location

Tags: spring-tool-suite

Where are default values for tasks and configurations stored in STS for Gradle projects please? Can they be displayed in an Eclipse UI?

Thanks in advance for your consideration!

Comment: You'll have to add more detail to your question. I have absolutely no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Ok.  I have STS installed on top of Eclipse.  I can open a cmd window and execute > gradle properties which renders a list of "stuff".  I'm new to STS and Gradle and trying to understand "what's under the hood"!  What I'm trying to determine is (a)are there files where the values are displayed or (b) are the hardcoded or programmatically arrived at during runtime.  My guess it's a combination of both.  I was looking for a catalog of default values for available keys to better understand what's available and how to impact the behavior of the tool.  Thanks For Responding!  :-)

Comment: I'm sorry but that question is just a little too broad to give you a good answer. Maybe start by learning a bit more about gradle itself and you'll be able to ask more pointed questions. A good place to start might be the gradle docs: https://gradle.org/documentation/